# php jquery append

Tags: php, jquery, append

does anyone know a way to get php working with jquery append()?
say we have

```
 $('.class0').click(function(){
        $('.class1').append('<?=PHPCODE?>');
    });
```

How do we get the php to work after append?
Thanks!

Comment: php generate static htmls and jQuery handle static htmls, so, it is not the same matter

Comment: After append? What you mean? You want to append data generated by PHP?

Comment: you mean something like this? `$('.class0').click(function(){ $('.class1').append('<?php echo 'foobar'; ?>'); });`

Comment: ahh, looking back at this i understand what a retarded question that was

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

**Document HTML(index.php)**

```
<?php
    include( 'config.php' ); // Example

    $foo = "<span style='color:red;'>WTF</span>" //OR <span style="color:red;">WTF</span>
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $.ready(function()
            {
                $('.element').click(function()
                {
                    $(this).append('<?php echo str_replace("'","\'",$foo);?>');
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#" class="element">Element</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

> 1. Use `<?php echo $foo; ?>`, `<?=$foo;?>` not is recomendated.
> 2. Escape especial characters, example : **'** (simple quot).
> 3. Use Smarty Template PHP Framework

***Smarty Template PHP Framework***

> **vista.php( MVC OOP )**
>
> ```
> <?php
>     class myClass
>     {
>         public function myMethodName()
>         {
>             $var = '<span>text</span>';
>             $this->template->assign( 'foo' , $var );
>             $this->template->display('myTemplate.html');
>         }
>     }
> ?>
> ```
>
> **vista.php( NO OOP )**
>
> ```
> <?php
>     $var = '<span>text</span>';
>     $smarty = new Smarty;
>     $smarty->assign( 'foo' , $var );
>     $smarty->display( 'myTemplate.html' );
> ?>
> ```
>
> **myTemplate.html**
>
> ```
> <html>
>     <head>
>         <title>{$title}</title>
>     </head>
>     <body>
>         {if $text}
>             {$text}
>             <ul>
>                 {foreach from=$list item=li}
>                     <li>{$li}</li>
>                 {/foreach}
>             </ul>
>         {/if}
>     </body>    
> </html>
> ```

[See and read Smarty Documentation](http://www.smarty.net/)

Answer (score 3):

Jquery is javascript and it is executed on the browser while php is a server-side script so in theory a PHP script always run first before any javascript. If you wish to run any php script after the page has finished loading (e.g. when a user click on a button), you need to do an AJAX call. ($.get(), $.load(), etc are examples using jquery)

In more details to your editted question:
With your code, the php script you write inside append will be rendered as plain text. Instead, do the ajax call before the append, and store the result of the ajax call in a variable. Then use: append(variable).

You might also be interested to do some DOM manipulation, which is more efficient if you're loading a huge text from your php script. You can return a JSON object from the php script then use a combinations of appends to create the desired result. This reduces the amount of data that needs to be transfered, but the javascript code could be lengthy.